# Problems with Excel function SUM.IF

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to sum a column of an Excel tab (depending on the content of another column) which can have different names.

Therefore I dynamically build the name of the tab and then use it in the SUMIF-function.

However, I get `#REFERENCE!` error and I don't know why?! I can reference single cells this way but not a range which I have to in this case. Can someone see what I'm doing wrong or maybe help me with a workaround?

`=SUMIF(INDIRECT(CHAR(39)&Settings!$D$3&"-V"&L$7&CHAR(39)&"!B3:B100";FALSE);B44;INDIRECT(CHAR(39)&Settings!$D$3&"-V"&L$7&CHAR(39)&"!H3:H100";FALSE))`

Area to sum as you can see below:-

[image: Area to sum as you can see below]

Cell where I want the sum to be:-

[image: Cell where I want the sum to be]

Comment: perhaps provide a screenshot of what you are working with?

Comment: You are passing `INDIRECT()` `FALSE` as the second argument, this means that it is expecting a formula in R1C1 format, you are giving it A1 style formula

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor nice catch

Comment: I changed the argument to `TRUE` but that didn't help at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&YEAR($E$5)&"-V"&L$7&"'!$M$3:$M$10"),"*"&$C9,INDIRECT("'"&YEAR($E$5)&"-V"&L$7&"'!$O$3:$O$10"))`

This is the correct use (note I have used the actual character `'` instead of CHAR(39))

The wildcard is used to match anything before the cells content as your data contains `PL` before it and also note the use of absolute referencing.

You will need to change the `,` to `;` to match your regional settings...

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I will try this. However, I saw that the `PL`should be there in the matching cell. My mistake...